# when assigning to a variable list index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
numb = input()
lis = list(map(int, numb.split()))
lis.sort()
a = lis[n]
for i in (0,len(lis)):
    if lis[i]=[a]
        print (lis[i-1])
```

I tried this and when I enter input of 5 for n and the lis as 24689 it says there is an error in the line where a=lis[n] saying the list index is out of range.

Comment: python indexes start from 0. a list with 5 elements has indexes from 0 upto 4 only.

Comment: What do you expect it should for `lis[i-1]` when `i=0`? There is another error in `a = lis[n]`. Try learning about indexes in Python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the line

```
for i in (0,len(lis)):
```

Lists are zero-based so the valid indexes are from `0` to `len(lis) - 1`. `len(lis)` is indeed out of range.

Also, notice that the above line of code means that `i` will receive only 2 values - `0` and `len(lis)`. Is that what you really mean? If you meant to go over all the indexes, you will need to do

```
for i in range(len(lis)):
```

`range(n)` is an iterator that returns the values from `0` to `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this code. Firstly, you need to change your for statement to `for i in range(0, len(lis))` because you're not currently calling the range function.

Also, on the first iteration, it will try to access index -1, which is the last element in the list. A better idea is to change your range function to `range(0, len(lis) - 1)`, and changing the print statement on the last line to `print(lis[i])` to fix the problem of receiving the last element by using the index -1.

P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Keep note that what you thought would happen on your third line wasn't the case and is 1 of the 2 problems of your error message. and that 1 problem was due to one single function you used which I have sequentially demonstration below;

I assume you were expecting each character of the string '24689' to be transformed to an integer by the map() function*, then converted to a list by the list() function*, then stored in the Variable ...lis... for later further usage. You were expecting something like `[2,4,6,8,9]` as Lis`.
Well you almost had that if not for your decision to use split() on Numb.

> The Split function will run first and turn the '24689' into a
> different iterable, in this case changing '24689' to a list ['24689'].
> Then the map() will map every item in this iterable ['24689'] to an
> integer. In this case only 1 item exist in the list which is '24689'.
> So it maps that item as an integer.
>
> Then the list() function stores this single item which is now an
> integer in a list owned by the variable Lis. So you finally get
> [24689]. And this is different from your [2,4,6,8,9] expectation.

As I've demonstrated above, so the cause of all this problem was your decision to use Split().
if you take away the split(), then;

> the map() will no longer see just one Item but rather '2' '4' '6' '8'
> '9' because a string '24689' is an iterable, with 5 individual items in
> your case. So the map() runs over all these 5 items in your Numb string and
> maps/transforms them to individual integers respectively. Then finally
> the List() would have stored all these beautiful individual integers
> in a list Owned by the variable Lis.And you get your desired [2,4,6,8,9] in return for the Variable Lis.

So the correct statement for that very line is:

```
lis = list(map(int, numb)) // This line should now produce [2,4,6,8,9]
```

The second problem of your error was the value you assigned to the index variable 'n' of list[n]. I assume you wanted to fetch the fifth item in the list. This 'n' is the linear count of items(in your case the individual numbers - 2,4,6,8,9). This counting start from 0 for the first letter instead of 1. Normally when you count items, the first letter is 1 but for index count in python list[n], the first letter is 0 instead of 1 so in your case the fifth item will be indexed as 4 since index count start from 0. So your 'n' input should be 4

**These 2 solutions above solves your the specific error you mentioned.**

BUT aside from your question above, your entire code will still run into another error even if the above solutions are implemented. This is Due to errors on these following lines as well:

**On line 6**:

```
for i in (0,len(lis)): //Wrong due to NO function name called before '(0, len(lis))'.
```

We will logically assume you want to use the *range function*

correct expression on LINE 6 is:

```
for i in range(0, len(lis)):
```

**On Line 7**:

```
if lis[i]=[a] //Three problems on this line...
```

First, you can't compare two objects with the operator '='. instead use '=='

Second, [a] is a meaningless value in your expression... Does comparing that to a number look right to you? I bet No. ***Remember [a] is not the same as the variable 'a'.***

> a = lis[n], while [a] = [lis[n]]

> So the correct expression there should be ***'a'*** and not ***'[a]'***

Last, you need to add ':' after every "if", "for" or "while" expression..
Here is how LINE 7 should CORRECTLY look like,

`if lis[i] == a:`

All the above solutions should satisfy your need. So the complete correct code for your script should look like this:

```
n = int(input())
numb = input()
lis = list(map(int, numb))
lis.sort()
a = lis[n]
for i in range(0,len(lis)):
    if lis[i] == a:
        print (lis[i-1])
```